# De-Serialization of a nested object tree using WCF DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, deserialization, datacontractserializer

I have the following SOAP XML Response

```
<startProcessResponseDDWEBCall xmlns="http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices">
     <ProcessInstanceOid>13430</ProcessInstanceOid>
     <Return>
        <DDWEBCallResponseData>
           <DDWEBCallOutput xmlns="http://www.infinity.com/bpm/model/OmniLinkServices/DDWEBCallOutput">
              <CommonResponse xmlns=""/>
              <reportContent xmlns=""><![CDATA[<HTML><BODY><P>The OmniPlus Host Server process DDWEB had the following error:  </P><P><TEXT="FF000">E23 TX00087 Textfile not found: TestScript @ 000003\\\                                                                                                    </TEXT></P><P>processing terminated</P></BODY></HTML>]]></reportContent>
           </DDWEBCallOutput>
        </DDWEBCallResponseData>
     </Return>
  </startProcessResponseDDWEBCall>
```

This is the SOAP body of a WCF web service call response.  I have the following object hierarchy to represent the response

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://www.infinity.com/bpm/model/OmniLinkServices/DDWEBCallOutput")]
public class OmniLinkExecuteScriptOutput
{   
    public string CommonResponse { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "reportContent")]
    public string ReportContent { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices")]
public class OmniLinkExecuteScriptResponseData
{    
    [DataMember(Name="DDWEBCallOutput")]
    public OmniLinkExecuteScriptOutput Output { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices")]    
public class OmniLinkExecuteScriptReturn
{ 
    [DataMember(Name="DDWEBCallResponseData")]
    public OmniLinkExecuteScriptResponseData ReponseData { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(WrapperName = "startProcessResponseDDWEBCall", WrapperNamespace = "http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices", IsWrapped = true)]
public class OmniLinkExecuteScriptResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "ProcessInstanceOid", Namespace = "http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices")]
    public string ProcessInstanceOid { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "Return", Namespace = "http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices")]
    public OmniLinkExecuteScriptReturn Return { get; set; }
}
```

The object OmniLinkExecuteScriptResponse is the return type of a method call.  Everything is deserialized fine except for the inner most object, the object representing the DDWEBCallOutput node.  I don't see any errors in the WCF plumbing, and the value of the Output property on the OmniLinkExecuteScriptResponseData object is always null.

Can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are applying the [`[DataContract(Namespace = "...")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.namespace(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes at the wrong level in your class hierarchy.  This attribute controls the namespace to which all data *members* of an instance of a type are serialized, and in addition controls the root element namespace if the instance is being serialized as such.

Thus you need to do the following:

```
// Its members are in the empty namespace
[DataContract(Namespace = "")] 
public class OmniLinkExecuteScriptOutput
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CommonResponse { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="reportContent")]
    public string ReportContent { get; set; }
}

// Its members are in the DDWEBCallOutput namespace
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.infinity.com/bpm/model/OmniLinkServices/DDWEBCallOutput")] 
public class OmniLinkExecuteScriptResponseData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "DDWEBCallOutput")]
    public OmniLinkExecuteScriptOutput Output { get; set; }
}

// Its members are in the OmniLinkServices namespace
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://eclipse.org/stardust/models/generated/OmniLinkServices")] 
public class OmniLinkExecuteScriptReturn
{
    [DataMember(Name = "DDWEBCallResponseData")]
    public OmniLinkExecuteScriptResponseData ReponseData { get; set; }
}
```

`OmniLinkExecuteScriptResponse` can remain unchanged.